# What articles are needed in document titles?

Tags: articles

There seems to be a general consensus that some articles can be omitted from movie, book or newspaper titles. Can this be generalised and applied to any document titles such as titles of technical reports or software user manuals?

Please consider the following title of a technical document (where "TG Platform" is a product name):

> **TG Platform Architecture from Engineering Perspective**

Can it be like that, or should it be changed to one of these?

> **TG Platform Architecture from an Engineering Perspective**
>   **The TG Platform Architecture from an Engineering Perspective**

.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is largely a matter of house style, but I think most readers would expect to see, even in a heading, *TG Platform Architecture from an Engineering Perspective*. There is perhaps greater flexibility over whether to start the heading with *The*.